# Low power circuit that powers an LED but should not shock the human user

Tags: circuit-design, low-power

Need help making a circuit that requires very low current  so that in case a human comes in contact he/she should not be shocked. Also a small buzzer or Led needs to powered through this circuit. The aim of this circuit is that when two components on the machine come in contact with each other the user must become aware.Something that is similar to the continuity mode on a multi meter.I need to use a 5V 3A supply as it will be powering another component.

There is a possibility that the user of the machine may touch one of the components, the current should be so low that the resistance of the body should be enough. I would also like to know if I need to add additional resistors to drop the current further and also add a fuse so that in case anything goes wrong the fuse can break and the user is always protected.

[image]

Comment: When the two contacts come into contact, if no further action is taken, will the contacts eventually damage themselves due to progressive forces developing. In other words, be clearer about the "thing".

Comment: Hey I am not good with this subject. I do not know what progressive forces developing means. The contacts will not get damaged due to current flow through it. They will be made of brass and aluminium. The two contacts will be in contact only a few seconds after which the user will move them to another place.

Comment: I'm talking about mechanical damage if nothing is done to stop things. Be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what mechanisms we are talking about here. Protection of the user from electric shock seems well down the "to do" list. Top seems to be automatic mechanical fault prevention.

Comment: You won't get shocked when using a 5V 3A power source. Skin impedance is simply too big to draw the current needed to get shocked.

Comment: @Andyaka there will not be any mechanical damage, the mechanism used to lift will be a screw. There will be another sensor like an optical sensor to stop the objects from crashing and causing mechanical damage. Mechanism used is "screw rod for lifting". Protection from crashing "optical switch" this switch will be triggered when the parts are close by, we need to bring the two components to the point where they are touching by adjusting a spring height. and once they touch the user gets a feed back signal.

Comment: @Swedgin Just for clarity , I want to make sure that the user does not feel anything, even like a small tingly feeling can be avoided as much as possible. like when we touch a multi meter we don't feel anything when its on continuity mode, some thing like that

Comment: Oxides on the metal surfaces will make contact-detection hit and miss unless a high impedance voltage (circa 400 volts) is used. Been there, read the book etc...

Comment: @HussainBhavnagarwala Yeah, I touched both terminals of my 5V 3A usb powersupply many times (thanks to the great connectors of apple). Never got a shock. Also, lets take skin resistance as 10K. So current through the skin is 300uA. You won't feel that

Comment: The aluminium will create a layer of oxide above it to protect it self. So the oxide layer will prevent the current from flowing ?. What if I change the aluminium to stainless steel or a some other non-expensive material where this can work ?. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @swedgin Thank you , will give it a try with my 5v 3A smps today !

Comment: Fuses do not protect against electric shock - you cannot get a conventional fuse with a low enough current rating to protect against shock. They are designed to prevent fires from the wires melting, which occurs at much higher currents than electric shock, and should be at much higher currents than your circuit will draw in normal operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 5V you are already in pretty safe territory as far as human contact is concerned. A representative standard for electrical hazards is [ECMA-287:](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-287.pdf). 
You can use a series resistor of say 10K or more to limit the max current to less than 0.5 mA even in the event of very small skin resistance (which would only happen e.g. with an open wound). The resistor would keep you in the range of ES1 level exposure even in the event of "abnormal" conditions. You could in principle go much larger with the resistor, like 1 Meg or more, depending on other sources of noise. E.g. is there a large motor motor nearby?

I would recommend using a MOSFET to turn on your LED and/or audible alarm. You should protect the gate of the MOSFET with a Zener diode.

If we suppose the bottom plate is at ground in your figure and the top needs to be energized to +5 V then a reasonable circuit that would fit in one box could be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the circuit diagram is very helpful, I will build this and get back to you !

Comment: I built this circuit and it works well, I had one minor problem. The speaker that was attached to the collector side on 12 V made a small buzzing sound even when the top and bottom piece were not in contact. When they did make contact the sound became louder and properly audible. Any reason to why that happens.

Comment: Hi , I realized that this happens in an open circuit that does not have a pull up or a pull down resistor, I am wondering where I should add it ?